# Changing Tensor Dimensions in Dueling Deep Q-Network (DQN) Training

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm currently implementing a Dueling Deep Q-Network (DQN) using PyTorch to train an agent in the Gym's Ms. Pacman environment. The training seems to start fine, but after a few episodes (specifically after about 100 episodes), I realize that the dimensions of the input tensor for my model start to change, causing instability in training.

I'm using a code structure that includes classes such as ObservationBuffer, ExperienceBuffer, FrameSkippingAgent, DuelingDQN, and Agent. The model is trained using a Double DQN approach, and I am having difficulty identifying the source of this problem in the tensor dimension changes.

Some important observations:
I'm using a GPU (CUDA) to speed up training.
The input observation dimensions for the Dueling DQN model are correct at first, but begin to change after a few episodes more than 200

Questions:
What could be causing these changes in tensor dimensions during training?

Thanks in advance for any guidance or suggestions that might help resolve this issue. I'm happy to provide more details if needed.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import torch 
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from collections import namedtuple, deque  
import gym
import torch.nn.functional as F

  Experience = namedtuple('Experience', ('state', 'action', 'reward', 'done', 'next_state'))

class ObservationBuffer:
def __init__(self, buffer_size=4):
    self.buffer_size = buffer_size
    self.buffer = []

def add_observation(self, observation):
    if len(self.buffer) >= self.buffer_size:
        self.buffer.pop(0)  # Remove the oldest observation if the buffer is full
    self.buffer.append(observation)

def get_buffer(self):
    return self.buffer

class ExperienceBuffer:
def __init__(self, capacity):
    self.buffer = deque(maxlen=capacity)

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.buffer)

def append(self, experience):
    self.buffer.append(experience)

def sample(self, batch_size):
    indices = np.random.choice(len(self.buffer), batch_size, replace=False)
    states, actions, rewards, dones, next_states = zip(*[self.buffer[idx] for idx in indices])
    return np.array(states), np.array(actions), \
           np.array(rewards, dtype=np.float32), np.array(dones, dtype=np.uint8), \
           np.array(next_states)

class FrameSkippingAgent:
def __init__(self, env_name, skip_frames=4, buffer_capacity=10000):
    self.env = gym.make(env_name)
    self.skip_frames = skip_frames
    self.observation_buffer = ObservationBuffer(buffer_size=4)
    self.experience_buffer = ExperienceBuffer(capacity=buffer_capacity)

@property
def action_space(self):
    return self.env.action_space

def preprocess_frame(self, frame):
    if isinstance(frame, tuple):
        frame_1, _ = frame
    else:
        frame_1 = frame

    img = np.reshape(frame_1, [210, 160, 3]).astype(np.float32)
    img = img[:, :, 0] * 0.229 + img[:, :, 1] * 0.587 + img[:, :, 2] * 0.114
    resized_screen = cv2.resize(img, (84, 84), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    x_t = np.reshape(resized_screen, [84,84,1])
    x_t = (x_t - x_t.min()) / (x_t.max() - x_t.min())
    x_t = (x_t * 255.0).astype(np.uint8)

    return x_t

def reset(self):
    state = self.env.reset()
    preprocessed_state = self.preprocess_frame(state)
    self.observation_buffer = ObservationBuffer(buffer_size=4)
    self.observation_buffer.add_observation(preprocessed_state)
    return self.observation_buffer.get_buffer()

def step(self, action):
    total_reward = 0

    for _ in range(self.skip_frames):
        state, reward, terminated, truncated, info = self.env.step(action)
        total_reward += reward
        self.observation_buffer.add_observation(self.preprocess_frame(state))
        if terminated:
            break

    current_state = self.observation_buffer.get_buffer()
    
    # Get the next state after one frame-skipped action
    next_state, _, _, _, _ = self.env.step(action)
    next_state = self.preprocess_frame(next_state)
    experience = Experience(state=current_state, action=action, reward=total_reward, done=terminated, next_state=next_state)

    self.experience_buffer.append(experience)

    return current_state, total_reward, terminated, truncated, info

 class DuelingDQN(nn.Module):
 def __init__(self, input_shape, n_actions):
    super(DuelingDQN, self).__init__()

    self.conv = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(input_shape[0], 64, kernel_size=8, stride=4),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=4, stride=2),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=1),
        nn.ReLU()
    )

    conv_out_size = self._get_conv_out(input_shape)
    
    # Separate the network into two streams for value and advantage
    self.value_stream = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(conv_out_size, 512),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(512, 1)
    )

    self.advantage_stream = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(conv_out_size, 512),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(512, n_actions)
    )

def _get_conv_out(self, shape):
    o = self.conv(torch.zeros(1, *shape))
    return int(np.prod(o.size()))

def forward(self, x):
    x = x.float()
    x = x.to("cuda")

    x = self.conv(x).view(x.size()[0], -1)

    value = self.value_stream(x)
    advantage = self.advantage_stream(x)

    # Combine value and advantage to get Q-values
    q_values = value + (advantage - advantage.mean(dim=1, keepdim=True))

    return q_values

class Agent:
def __init__(self, env, exp_buffer):
    self.env = env
    self.exp_buffer = exp_buffer
    self._reset()

def _reset(self):
    self.state = self.env.reset()
    self.total_reward = 0.0

def select_action_ddqn(self, net, state, epsilon=0.0, device="cuda"):
    if np.random.random() < epsilon:
        action = self.env.action_space.sample()
        q_value = 0.0  # Assign some default value when action is random
    else:
        state_a = np.array([state], copy=False)
        state_v = torch.tensor(state_a, dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
        state_v = state_v.squeeze(0)

        q_vals_online = net(state_v)
        _, act_v_online = torch.max(q_vals_online, dim=1)

        # Use target network for Q-value estimation
        q_vals_target = target_net(state_v).detach()
        q_value = q_vals_target[0, act_v_online.item()]

        action = int(act_v_online.item())

    return action, q_value

@torch.no_grad()
def play_step(self, net, epsilon=0.0, device="cuda"):
    done_reward = None

    action, q_value = self.select_action_ddqn(net, self.state, epsilon, device)

    new_state, reward, terminated, truncated, info = self.env.step(action)

    self.state = np.moveaxis(self.state, -1, 0)
    new_state = np.moveaxis(new_state, -1, 0)

    if isinstance(new_state, list):
        new_state = np.array(new_state)
    if isinstance(self.state, list):
        self.state = np.array(self.state)

    self.total_reward += reward

    exp = Experience(self.state, action, reward, terminated, new_state)
    self.exp_buffer.append(exp)
    self.state = new_state

    if terminated:
        done_reward = self.total_reward
        self._reset()

    return done_reward

env_name = 'MsPacman-v0'
buffer_capacity = 10000
observation_buffer = ObservationBuffer(buffer_size=4)
experience_buffer = ExperienceBuffer(capacity=buffer_capacity)

def calc_loss(batch, net, tgt_net, device):
states, actions, rewards, dones, next_states = batch

states_v = torch.tensor(np.array(states, copy=False)).to(device)
next_states_v = torch.tensor(np.array(next_states, copy=False)).to(device)
actions_v = torch.tensor(actions, dtype=torch.int64).to(device)
rewards_v = torch.tensor(rewards).to(device)
done_mask = torch.BoolTensor(dones).to(device)

state_action_values = net(states_v).gather(1, actions_v.unsqueeze(-1)).squeeze(-1)

with torch.no_grad():
    next_state_values = tgt_net(next_states_v).max(1)[0]
    next_state_values[done_mask] = 0.0
    next_state_values = next_state_values.detach()

expected_state_action_values = next_state_values * GAMMA + rewards_v

# Use Huber loss instead of MSE loss
loss = F.smooth_l1_loss(state_action_values, expected_state_action_values)

return loss


  frame_skip_agent = FrameSkippingAgent(env_name)
  experience_buffer = frame_skip_agent.experience_buffer
  agent = Agent(frame_skip_agent, experience_buffer)

 # Training parameters
 MAX_EPISODES = 1000
 MAX_STEPS_PER_EPISODE = 10000
 BATCH_SIZE = 128
 GAMMA = 0.99
 LEARNING_RATE = 0.0001
 TARGET_UPDATE = 1000
 EPS_START = 1.0
 EPS_END = 0.02
 EPS_DECAY = 100000

optimizer = optim.Adam(online_net.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)
experience_buffer = ExperienceBuffer(capacity=10000)

# Training loop
for episode in range(MAX_EPISODES):
  frame_skip_agent.reset()
  total_reward = 0.0

for step in range(MAX_STEPS_PER_EPISODE):
    # Play a step and store the experience
    epsilon = max(EPS_END, EPS_START - episode / EPS_DECAY)
    done_reward = agent.play_step(online_net, epsilon=epsilon, device="cuda")
    if done_reward is not None:
       print(f"Episode {episode + 1}, Total Reward: {done_reward}")
       break

    # Sample a batch from the experience buffer and perform a Q-network update
    if len(experience_buffer) > BATCH_SIZE:
        batch_states, batch_actions, batch_rewards, batch_dones, batch_next_states = experience_buffer.sample(BATCH_SIZE)
        batch_states = torch.tensor(batch_states, dtype=torch.float32).to("cuda")
        batch_actions = torch.tensor(batch_actions, dtype=torch.int64).to("cuda")
        batch_rewards = torch.tensor(batch_rewards, dtype=torch.float32).to("cuda")
        batch_dones = torch.BoolTensor(batch_dones).to("cuda")
        batch_next_states = torch.tensor(batch_next_states, dtype=torch.float32).to("cuda")

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = calc_loss((batch_states, batch_actions, batch_rewards, batch_dones, batch_next_states), online_net, target_net, device="cuda")
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    # Update target network periodically
    if step % TARGET_UPDATE == 0:
        target_net.load_state_dict(online_net.state_dict())

    # Check if the episode is done
    if done_reward is not None:
        print(f"Episode {episode + 1}, Total Reward: {total_reward}")
        break
```